# Matplotlib log-log plot - only show powers of ten on y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Assume I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x =[10, 14, 19, 26, 36, 50, 70, 98, 137, 191, 267, 373, 522, 730, 1021, 1429, 2000, 2800, 3919, 5486, 7680] 
y = [ 0.0085,  0.006900000000000001,  0.007600000000000001,  0.007600000000000001,  0.01,  0.008700000000000003,  0.0094,  0.008800000000000002,  0.0092,  0.009,  0.009999999999999998,  0.010099999999999998,  0.010899999999999998,  0.010899999999999998, 0.011,  0.0115,   0.0115,  0.0118,  0.013000000000000001,  0.0129, 0.0131]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
ax1.plot(x,y,linewidth=1) 
ax1.set_xscale('log') 
ax1.set_yscale('log') 
plt.show()
```

the result is as follows:

[image]

What I want to do is to remove ticks on the y-axis that are **not** a power of 10. In this particular example, remove 9x10^-3, 8x10^-3 etc. and only keep 10^-2.

I've tried some other suggestions e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723744/matplotlib-log-axis-display-powers-of-10-only) but none of them worked..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the powers of 10 between your min and max y values and then set the ticks directly with `ax1.set_yticks( y_ticks)`.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math 

x =[10, 14, 19, 26, 36, 50, 70, 98, 137, 191, 267, 373, 522, 730, 1021, 1429, 2000, 2800, 3919, 5486, 7680] 
y = [ 0.0085,  0.006900000000000001,  0.007600000000000001,  0.007600000000000001,  0.01,  0.008700000000000003,  0.0094,  0.008800000000000002,  0.0092,  0.009,  0.009999999999999998,  0.010099999999999998,  0.010899999999999998,  0.010899999999999998, 0.011,  0.0115,   0.0115,  0.0118,  0.013000000000000001,  0.0129, 0.0131]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
ax1.plot(x,y,linewidth=1) 
ax1.set_xscale('log') 
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ymin_pow = math.floor(math.log10(min(y)))
ymax_pow = math.ceil(math.log10(max(y)))

y_ticks = [10**i for i in range(ymin_pow, ymax_pow + 1)]

# optional: bound the limits 
if y_ticks[0] < min(y):
    y_ticks = y_ticks[1:]
if y_ticks[-1] > max(y):
    y_ticks = y_ticks[-1:]

ax1.set_yticks(y_ticks, [str(i) for i in y_ticks])

# un-comment out the following line to have your labels 
# not in scientific notation
# ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok but can you please show me how? And you probably mean yticks?

Comment: Yes sorry I did mean yticks. Answer updated with more code.

Comment: So this turns out to have the exact opposite effect.. Any thoughts? https://i.imgur.com/xQ9vFF1.png

Comment: Found the bug, it should be math.floor(math.log(min(y),10)) (it defaults to base e). However now the problem is that in this particular example it makes 10^-3 appear as well which changes the plot quite a lot.

Comment: Good catch -- edited to use `math.log10`. If the 10^(-3) showing up is a problem you could bound the axis to the min and max values -- answer edited above.

Comment: Still no good. Even if I set `ax1.set_yticks([0.01])` the plot becomes again as in the beginning with all the non-power ticks..

Comment: Unfortunately your still doesn't work, now it outputs weird ticks https://i.imgur.com/Fzqieb8.png

Comment: This is the expected behaviour now -- in this version, the ticks are at the max and min of the data (and at 10^(-2)). In the old version where the ticks are at 10^(-1) and 10^(-3) too, the graph is scaled so it looks really compressed (as you said before). You've gotta choose the lesser of 2 evils :P

Comment: You can go back to the original scaling by removing the lines "y_ticks[0] = min(y)
y_ticks[-1] = max(y)"

Comment: I see.. Well I'm hoping there's another solution that just outputs the original plot but without the ticks that are not a power of 10..